# How to include multiple address prefixes in the same admin rule using Terraform AzureRm

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

I am using azurerm_network_manager_admin_rule resource to create an admin rule for the virtual network manager resource. I can only pass in one address prefix per rule. Is there a way to use multiple address prefixes in the same rule?

Here is the error message:

```
Error: creating Network Manager Admin Rule: (Rule Name "example" / Rule Collection Name "example-rule-collection" / Security Admin Configuration Name "ISD" / Network Manager Name "AzureNetworkManager" / Resource Group "resourceGroup-test"): network.AdminRulesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="AddressPrefix [1.1.1.1/1,2.2.2.2/2,3.3.3.3/3,4.4.4.4/4] has invalid format."
│
│   with module.avnm.azurerm_network_manager_admin_rule.avnm-security-admin-collection-rule["example"],
│   on ..\..\main.tf line 31, in resource "azurerm_network_manager_admin_rule" "avnm-security-admin-collection-rule":
│   31: resource "azurerm_network_manager_admin_rule" "avnm-security-admin-collection-rule" {
│
│ creating Network Manager Admin Rule: (Rule Name "example" / Rule Collection Name "example-rule-collection" / Security Admin Configuration Name "ISD" / Network Manager Name "AzureNetworkManager" / Resource Group "resourceGroup-test"): network.AdminRulesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: 
│ autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="AddressPrefix [1.1.1.1/1,2.2.2.2/2,3.3.3.3/3,4.4.4.4/4] has invalid format."
```

(some names and the IP addresses have been changed from original error message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `azurerm network manager admin rule` resource, it is not possible to use **"multiple address prefixes"** in a single `admin rule`.

**Alternatively,** you can create multiple admin rules, each with a unique address prefix.

***Eg:***

```bash
resource "azurerm_network_manager_admin_rule"  "first-rule" {}
resource "azurerm_network_manager_admin_rule"  "second-rule"{}
```

According to the [terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_manager_admin_rule), it is possible to create multiple address prefixes inside the `destination or source address` blocks. I tried it in my environment after making few changes to the sample script and it worked for me as follows.

`main.tf`:

```bash
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "<resourcegroup>"
  location = "EastUs"
}

resource "azurerm_network_manager" "main" {
  name                = "<networkmanager>"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  scope {
    subscription_ids = [data.azurerm_subscription.current.id]
  }
  scope_accesses = ["Connectivity", "SecurityAdmin"]
  description    = "network manager"
}

resource "azurerm_network_manager_network_group" "main" {
  name               = "<networkgroup>"
  network_manager_id = azurerm_network_manager.main.id
}

resource "azurerm_network_manager_security_admin_configuration" "example" {
  name               = "<admin-conf>"
  network_manager_id = azurerm_network_manager.main.id
}

resource "azurerm_network_manager_admin_rule_collection" "main" {
  name                            = "<admin-rule-collection>"
  security_admin_configuration_id = azurerm_network_manager_security_admin_configuration.main.id
  network_group_ids               = [azurerm_network_manager_network_group.main.id]
}

resource "azurerm_network_manager_admin_rule" "main" {
  name                     = "<adminrule>"
  admin_rule_collection_id = azurerm_network_manager_admin_rule_collection.main.id
  action                   = "Deny"
  direction                = "Outbound"
  priority                 = 1
  protocol                 = "Tcp"
  source_port_ranges       = ["80", "1024-65535"]
  destination_port_ranges  = ["80"]
  source {
    address_prefix_type = ""
    address_prefix      = "Internet"
  }
   destination {
    address_prefix_type = "IPPrefix"
    address_prefix      = "10.1.0.1"
  }
  destination {
    address_prefix_type = "IPPrefix"
    address_prefix      = "10.0.0.0/24"
  }
  description = "admin rule"
}
```

***Executed*** `terraform init` & ***validated*** the configuration using  `terraform validate`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform plan`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform apply`:

[image]

***Deployed successfully in portal with multiple destination address prefixes:***

[image]